# jQuery object in JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here be my first question!

I'm calling JSON via AJAX for use in a client side validation library. The library calls for me to specify where, for the current rule, I wish to insert the error message. For my static validation rules I can write an object such as:

```
{ 'errorlocation' : jQuery('[name="foo"]').closest('.bar') }
```

My validation library allows me to inject more rules after the first init, so when I submit my model by REST I could receive a server response with errors. I am currently developing that server response. I would prefer that the error response would simply be an array of validation rules so that I can later inject those rules into the same validation object that has already been created on my page. So within the response JSON I would require such a definition as that in the code snippet above.

It seems though that Backbone and jQuery's parse json algorithms can not evaluate the `jQuery()` value of the object even though jQuery is definitely available in the global namespace. So this doesn't work:

```
jQuery.parseJSON("{ 'errorlocation' : jQuery('[name=\"foo\"]').closest('.bar') }");
```

I have thought about just storing the "[name='foo']" and jQuerying after the parse but that doesn't work for the case where I want to chain, such as that above `.closest('.bar')`

Does anyone know of a JSON parser that will parse/allow variables located in the global namespace?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a data format, not a code format.  Generally you want to structure your system in a way that you're passing data from the server to the client, and then your client uses the data to determine an action.  So maybe you would pass the `foo` and `.bar` back as data, and another parameter to determine what function to run.

If you really HAVE to design it this way, and I advise against that,  you can use eval to evaluate an arbitrary string as javascript, like this:

```
var errorInfo = jQuery.parseJSON(
    "{ 'errorlocation' : \"jQuery('[name=\"foo\"]').closest('.bar')\" }");

eval(errorInfo.errorocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the whole jQuery call as a string, then running eval in the client side? Like this:

```
json = jQuery.parseJSON("{ 'errorlocation' : 'jQuery(\'[name=\"foo\"]\').closest('.bar')' }");
location = eval(json.errorlocation) //runs the jQuery string
```

Comment: Thanks mike, that would work though I would prefer to be able to stick the response straight into the validation library rather than having to perform one to many actions on it every time I load additional validation rules.